# Loop through an array and download web data from a link?

Tags: r

I'm trying to download data from Table2 from this link.
http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=aapl

I'd like to write all the elements in an array into a CSV file but I can't even get the loop working.  The paste function seems unnecessary, but that's all I could find after several Google searches.

```
library('rvest')
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")
for (i in 1 : length(stocks))

{ 

url <- sprintf(paste("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", stocks));
x<-read_html(paste("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", stocks))
html_table( x %>% html_nodes("table.snapshot-table2"))

}
```

Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: You probably want `paste0` rather than `paste`, but it would help if you clarified what exactly you mean by "doesn't work." Are you getting an error? Are you not getting what you expected -- and if so, describe what you expected?

Comment: BTW `sprintf` is not needed here: `sprintf(paste("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", stocks))`

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  Thanks for helping me see that.  Now, I have this:


library('rvest')

stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks))

{ 
url <- paste0("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=",stocks);
write.csv(html_table( x %>% html_nodes("table.snapshot-table2")), file = "C:/Users/excel/Desktop/MyData.csv")
}

That runs, but it doesn't give me the correct results.  I was hoping to get the Table2 data stacked one on top of the other, like ColumnB has all metrics for AXP, ColumnC has all metrics for BA, and so on and so forth.  How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `cbind` for that.

Comment: You should not raise new questions in comments. This is not a support thread. If you have a different question than the one you initially posted, you should start a new question/post.

Answer (score 0):

Unfamiliar with `rvest` package, you could however handle your html table extract with R's `XML` package, specifically its [readHTMLTable](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xml/docs/readhtmltable) function.

```
library(XML)

stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")

for (s in stocks) {
      url <- paste0("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", s)
      webpage <- readLines(url)
      html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)
      tableNodes <- getNodeSet(html, "//table")

      # ASSIGN TO STOCK NAMED DFS
      assign(s, readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[9]], 
                header= c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6",
                          "data7", "data8", "data9", "data10", "data11", "data12")))

      # ADD COLUMN TO IDENTIFY STOCK 
      df <- get(s)
      df['stock'] <- s
      assign(s, df)
}

# COMBINE ALL STOCK DATA 
stockdatalist <- cbind(mget(stocks))
stockdata <- do.call(rbind, stockdatalist)
# MOVE STOCK ID TO FIRST COLUMN
stockdata <- stockdata[, c(ncol(stockdata), 1:ncol(stockdata)-1)]

# SAVE TO CSV
write.table(stockdata, "C:\\Path\\To\\StockData.csv", sep=",", 
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)

# REMOVE TEMP OBJECTS
rm(df, stockdatalist)
```

---

To extract every stock indicator with its corresponding value as shown on website and assign to separate lists, consider using XML's [xpathSApply()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xml/docs/matchNamespaces) to XPath the needed table cell and row. Then append each returned xml value into list and combine lists to final dataframe:

```
for (s in stocks) {
  url <- paste0("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=", s)
  webpage <- readLines(url)
  html <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asText = TRUE)  

  for (row in 1:12) {
    for (col in seq(1, 12, 2)) {
      if (s == "AXP") {
        assign(xpathSApply(html, sprintf("//table[9]/tr[%d]/td[%d]", row, col), xmlValue)[1],
               xpathSApply(html, sprintf("//table[9]/tr[%d]/td[%d]", row, col+1), xmlValue)[1])
      } else {                    
        stocklist <- get(xpathSApply(html, sprintf("//table[9]/tr[%d]/td[%d]", row, col), xmlValue)[1])
        stocklist <- c(stocklist, 
                       xpathSApply(html, sprintf("//table[9]/tr[%d]/td[%d]", row, col+1), xmlValue)[1])
        assign(xpathSApply(html, sprintf("//table[9]/tr[%d]/td[%d]", row, col), xmlValue)[1],
               stocklist)
      }            
    }
  }      
}    

rm(stocklist, stock, url, html, webpage, row, col, s)      # REMOVE TEMP OBJECTS    
`EPS next Y` <- c("2.90%","14.21%","-21.84%","5.63%")      # CLEAN UP ONE LIST  

# COMBINE LISTS INTO DATA FRAME
lists <- as.list(ls())                                     # LIST OF STOCK INDICATORS
df <- data.frame(stocks=unlist(stocks))                    # CREATE DF

for (i in lists){
    slist <- get(i)
    df <- cbind(df, slist)                                 # ADD DF COLS
}

names(df) <- c("Stock", lists)                             # RENAME COLUMNS
```

Comment: Wow!  Awesome script Parfait!!  This does almost exactly what I want.  Is there an easy way to list stocks in row1 and all metrics in an array rather than a matrix?  So, under 'Recom', 'P/E would start, and under 'SMA20', 'EPS (ttm)' would start?  If it's a easy fix, please post the code.  If it's not easy to do, forget it, you've already given me a LOT more than I had a few hours ago!  Thanks again!!

Comment: Also, how do you know everything is in tableNodes[[9]]?  If I go to the link and hit F12 and then search for, let's say 'Market Cap, I can easily find the table that all the data is in.  It seems to be table-class=snapshot-table2.  I thought it was Table2, not Table9, but 9 seems to work.  Thanks.

Comment: See update using `xpathSApply()` which appends values of stock metrics to 72 lists and then at end appends all into one data frame (not too elegant but works). One metric returned more than 4 values so needed cleanup. As for knowing the `[[9]]`, I simply counted `<table>` in page source to needed section.